# Oh-My-Zsh remove duplicated path in directory stack

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, pushd

Without Oh-My-Zsh, I can `pushd` two identical path:

```
$ dirs
~
$ pushd Desktop
Desktop ~
$ pushd ~
~ Desktop ~
```

With Oh-My-Zsh:

```
$ dirs
~
$ pushd Desktop
Desktop ~
$ pushd ~
~ Desktop
```

How do I disable this? I want the original Zsh behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Insprired by [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/401707)) It is set in [`$ZSH/lib/directories.zsh`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/a7e30b26baa94bac99d9d05cf642bd1942ae1787/lib/directories.zsh#L2-L3):

```
setopt auto_pushd
setopt pushd_ignore_dups
```

`auto_pushd` makes `cd` behave the same as `pushd`. However, this would result in an directory stack overflow if you keep changing directory, so they set `pushd_ignore_dups` as well, to limit the stack. This is not a problem for me, since I disabled `auto_pushd`.

Therefore, add `unsetopt pushd_ignore_dups` in `~/.zshrc`.

#### Reference

- [Options - Zsh documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Changing-Directories)

Comment: So how are you use, i.e. `cd` into, a directory on the stack now?

Comment: @the_velour_fog Sorry, I don't do that in my daily workflow... I do not heavily rely on the directory stack feature. I `pushd` only when I need to poke to some directory to see some distant folder (e.g. `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/` in OS X), then `popd` back real quick. If I need to frequently switch between two directory for long, I prefer to open another tab for it.